# Conditional probability. Independence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, independence

Out of 100 cards with numbers 00; 01; 02; ... ... .; 98; 99 is chosen at random. Let X and Y, respectively, be the sum and product of the numbers on the selected card. Find the conditional probability of an event P (X = i | Y = 0), i = 0; 1; 2; ... ... ... 18;

Can you, please, explain why   **i**  changes in this interval i = 0; 1; 2; ... ... ... 18;, if we have 100 cards and, in general, what is the point of finding the conditional probability of the sum and product of the number on the card?

Comment: This is not clear.  How many cards are you choosing?  Are you choosing with or without replacement?

Comment: If $X$ is the sum of the two numbers on the selected card, then it is the sum of two numbers in the range $\{0,1,\dotsc,9\}$. Hence, $X$ takes values in the set $\{0,1,\dotsc,18\}$.

Comment: And are you really asking what "the point" of the question is?  It looks like a routine homework exercise, so I assume that the point is to get you to practice your technique with these sort of computations.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I need to substitute values i instead of  X and consider it as a conventional formula of conditional probability?

Comment: That is, we can say that $Y takes {0,1,...81}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with $Y=0$. This means at least one of the digits shown on the card is zero. That is the only way to achieve a product of 0. So, for the conditional probability, your sample space changes to the following cards:

$$00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90$$

Now, let's break it down:

$$P(X=i|Y=0) = \begin{cases} \tfrac{1}{19}, & i=0 \\ \tfrac{2}{19}, & 1\le i \le 9 \\ 0, & 9 < i\end{cases}$$

It is not possible to get a sum of 10 or more when one of the digits shown must be zero. For other products, you similarly limit your sample space. Then, from that limited sample space, you can calculate how many cards yield each possible sum.

Comment: Eternal,I understand correctly that in the interval from 10 to 18 it will be impossible to calculate the conditional probability?

Comment: It is possible to calculate the conditional probability. A probability of $0$ is still a calculated probability. Out of the nineteen cards that have a zero showing, how many of them have a sum of digits in the $10$ to $18$ range? Exactly $0$ of them. $$\tfrac{0}{19}=0$$ is a valid calculation.

Comment: @Eternal, Why is the probability in the 1 to 9 range equal2/19?

Comment: Out of the $19$ cards that include a $0$, how many of them have a sum of $1$? When you go through all $19$ cards, you find two that have that sum: $01, 10$. So, the probability is $\dfrac{2}{19}$. We can create the following chart: $$\begin{array}{c|c}\text{sum} & \text{cards} \\ \hline 0 & 00 \\ 1 & 01, 10\\ 2 & 02, 20 \\ 3 & 03, 30 \\ 4 & 04, 40 \\ 5 & 05, 50 \\ 6 & 06,60 \\ 7 & 07,70 \\ 8 & 08,80 \\ 9 & 09,90 \\ 10 & \\ 11 & \\ 12 & \\ 13 & \\ 14 & \\ 15 & \\ 16 & \\ 17 & \\ 18 &\end{array}$$